# How Do I Get The Current Executing Assembly's Path

Tags: c++, dll, pinvoke

I don't know how to explain this but I will try. Here is what I'm using :

C++ :

```
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) void c(char path[])
{
    //some code with the path.
}
```

C#:

```
[DllImport("DLL")]
static extern void c(char[] path);
```

As you can see I'm using an exported function from c++.
My question is, is there an easier way to get the path of the application **from the DLL** without passing it as a parameter to the exported function ?

Comment: `Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location)` I don't see how your P/Invoke code is related at all to what you're asking...

Comment: Are you asking how to get a calling managed assembly's executing directory from a P/invoked C++ function?

Comment: @ildjarn I want to get the path from the native dll, I can already do that but I'm asking if there is an easier way without the need to pass the parameter.

Comment: In that case your question was very unclear, as the existing answers indicate.

Comment: @ildjarn, I think my question was very clear when I said, "is there an easier way to get the path of the application without passing it as a parameter to the exported function ?" I'm sorry for any misunderstanding.

Comment: dllexport and dllimport are only used in DLLs. You don't use those keywords to refer to functions that are contained in other source files that are linked with the project. in main.c you need to prototype the function that is included in a different *.c file using extern keyword. how familiar are you with Importing / Exporting DLL function calls

Comment: It is a DLL ? I exported the function so I could use it in my C# project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is really easy, but takes some forethought:

The first thing to do is implement a `DllMain` in the native DLL, which will cache the module's handle when the DLL loads. That looks like:

```
EXTERN_C BOOL WINAPI DllMain(_In_ HINSTANCE hinstDLL, _In_ DWORD fdwReason, _In_opt_ LPVOID lpvReserved)
{
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(lpvReserved);

    if (fdwReason == DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH)
    {
        DisableThreadLibraryCalls(hinstDLL);

        g_Handle = hinstDLL;
    }

    return TRUE;
}
```

Later, when you want to get the name, just call [`GetModuleFileName`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683197%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), like so:

```
TCHAR dllName[MAX_PATH + 1];
GetModuleFileName(g_Handle, dllName, MAX_PATH);
```

The only complicated part, if you want to call it that, is storing the handle from DllMain. Calling `GetModuleHandle(NULL)` will give you the executing module's handle, not the DLL (same as `GetExecutingAssembly` in C#).

Comment: I'm getting this error: `'g_Handle' : undeclared identifier`, is there something missing I should declare?

Comment: You need an HINSTANCE (or HMODULE) called g_Handle, or anything else you like. It's just a global variable both the DllMain and later function can access.

Answer (score 2):

@peachykeen (who has a most excellent name) is right on with the [GetModuleFileName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683197%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) suggestion. The trick to get the EXE path is to pass NULL as the hModule parameter.

From MSDN:

hModule [in, optional] 
A handle to the loaded module whose path is being requested. *If this parameter is NULL, GetModuleFileName retrieves the path of the executable file of the current process.*

Comment: I wonder what this will return when the executable is a .Net assembly and the DLL is native. I suspect it'll be the .Net assembly's path, since that shows up in process explorer, but never tried it.

Comment: Yes, it returned the assembly path if I passed null instead of g_Handle. Thank you all.

Answer (score 0):

Path for standalone application and windows service(but not for websites):

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory
```

Comment: You got me wrong, I want to get the path from the native DLL.